# How to cleanse (overwrite with random bytes) std::string internal buffer?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

Consider a scenario, where `std::string` is used to store *a secret*. Once it is consumed and is no longer needed, it would be good to cleanse it, i.e overwrite the memory that contained it, thus hiding the *secret*.

`std::string` provides a function `const char* data()` returning a pointer to (since C++11) continous memory.

Now, since the memory is continous **and** the variable will be destroyed right after the cleanse due to scope end, would it be safe to:

```
char* modifiable = const_cast<char*>(secretString.data());
OpenSSL_cleanse(modifiable, secretString.size());
```

According to standard quoted here:

> $5.2.11/7 - Note: Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through the pointer, lvalue or pointer to data member resulting from a `const_cast` that casts away a `const-qualifier`<sup>68</sup> may produce undefined behavior (7.1.5.1).

That would advise otherwise, but do the conditions above (continuous, to-be-just-removed) make it safe?

Comment: Instead of using `OpenSSL_cleanse` and possible UB why not iterate through the string and assign it random values from a PRNG?

Comment: Also note starting in C++17 `data` is overloaded to return a non const pointer so you can use it then.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'd assume OpenSSL_cleanse is optimized to use as few `rand()` (or similiar) calls as possible, while guaranteeing acceptable safety. Imagine a case where `rand()` is called on hardware, and could be costly. Besides, reinventing the wheel... And another thing - as @ilotXXI stated in comment below - naive clear may be optimized away (usually is).

Comment: Note that there are several other things you need to do properly for secret handling. Among them are using mlock'd memory so it can't be written to disk in swap, making sure it is not crossing a cache line boundary so attackers can't try to detect things about it using hyperthreading and cache line bounce counts. Etc. Really look into just using a proper security library and use its data structures, not std::string.

Comment: @ZanLynx that is a very good set of tips. I did use a somewhat safe class for secret handling, with the `std::string` needed in just a little tiny interface to a 3rd party library, hence the issue. I will however look into the things you mentioned,

Comment: You know, you really don't want to use `std::string`, but an actual securestring-type to ensure **all** buffers get scrubbed. Take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107991/hacking-a-securestring-based-on-stdbasic-string-for-c for a way to hack `std::basic_string` to fill the need.

Comment: @NathanOliver You would then be hoping that the compiler doesn't see that the values aren't used and optimize out the writes. It's much better to use a function that's specifically documented to be safe for this use than to hope the compiler is dumb.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is probably safe. But not guaranteed.

However, since `C++11`, a `std::string` must be implemented as contiguous data so you can safely access its internal array using the address of its first element `&secretString[0]`.

```
if(!secretString.empty()) // avoid UB
{
    char* modifiable = &secretString[0];
    OpenSSL_cleanse(modifiable, secretString.size());
}
```

Comment: I personally like this answer, however, the first two sentences contain too much probability :) If the data ended in a read-only memory segment (or would be however optimized by the compiler to be read-only), could that cause the application to enter the UB area? (as in: is `operator&` much different than a `const_cast`)

Comment: @hauron Taking the address of a read-write element must produce a read-write pointer. I don't see how the compiler can mess with that concept tbh.

Comment: How could the data end in a read-only segment when it's allocated from the heap in a contiguous block, and written to (to store the null terminator after the string contents)? You get a `char*` this way, so you can write to it. The standard says it is undefined to write through the `const char*` returned by `data()`. One is obviously safe and one is explicitly undefined. There should be no question which to use.

Comment: @JonathanWakely and Galik: you are both correct. It is a modifiable value and it's a part of a continous block. Safe to modify.

Comment: The goal was to cleanse `std::string` internal buffer avoiding UB - this does it, simply.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: `std::string` does not promise to allocate anything. It only promises to return a pointer to a certain sequence of bytes. The only practical thing we can think of is to do this by allocation, but that is an implementation detail not a contract. To give one example: an implementation optimised for 1-byte strings could, without breaking a contract, avoid all memory allocation by returning (for a 1-byte string) a pointer to one out of 256 possible pre-built 1-byte strings in read-only memory.

Comment: @nugae, no it couldn't, because then you couldn't do `std::string s{"a"}; s[0] = 'b';`. It might not promise to allocate anything, but [string.require]p3 clearly talks about how it uses an allocator as needed, and says `reserve()` allocates. Here in the real world, it allocates, and I don't really care what hypothetical but non-conforming implementations that don't support modification do.

Answer (score 18):

The standard explicitly says you must not write to the `const char*` returned by `data()`, so don't do that.

There are perfectly safe ways to get a modifiable pointer instead:

```
if (secretString.size())
  OpenSSL_cleanse(&secretString.front(), secretString.size());
```

Or if the string might have been shrunk already and you want to ensure its entire capacity is wiped:

```
if (secretString.capacity()) {
  secretString.resize(secretString.capacity());
  OpenSSL_cleanse(&secretString.front(), secretString.size());
}
```

Comment: This, plus ensuring that you have `reserve`d enough space for the whole password before entering it into the string (or enlarging the buffer may leave parts of the password behind), is the answer. Although is even that enough to ensure that there is nowhere else that you're not `OpenSSL_cleanse`ing?

Comment: Question about capacity: in the case of a SSO string, could the call to resize move from inline-storage to heap-storage? (thus cleansing the heap-storage when the secret was stored inline) I don't quite see why it would but...

Comment: Only if it was written by an idiot. Adding elements while there is spare capacity() should never allocate, it would make `reserve()` completely pointless, although I don't see such a guarantee in the standard. If you don't trust your implementation to get that right then you definitely shouldn't be using `std::string` for sensitive data.

Comment: @MatthieuM: if you're worried about that you can cleanse, resize, cleanse again. It looks to me as if the standard allows `resize()` to invalidate iterators and references even if the new size is within the capacity, so the standard panders to (as Jonathan puts it) idiots.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Well, I think we all agree you probably shouldn't be using `std::string` for sensitive data anyway :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. yep, maybe I should have used markdown to say you _definitely_ shouldn't be using `std::string`

Answer (score 14):

std::string is a poor choice to store secrets. Since strings are copyable and sometimes copies go unnoticed, your secret may "get legs". Furthermore, string expansion techniques may cause multiple copies of fragments (or all of) your secrets.

Experience dictates a movable, non-copyable, wiped clean on destroy, unintelligent (no tricky copies under-the-hood) class.

Comment: It's the "wiped clean on destroy" subproblem that OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @DavidThomas thank you for the answer, and I agree. The use case for unfortunate `std::string` comes from a 3rd party library not leaving much choice.

Comment: I am asserting that the destructor is the best place for a wipe. The onus is on the class designer and not every instance of its use

Comment: @DavidThomas But the compiler may optimize away the reset in the destructor as it knows the object is not used anymore.

Comment: @DavidThomas consider this: `SecretHandler(std::string&& unprotected);` - how would you scrap the `unprotected` input? (that's what the question is about)

Comment: @NathanOliver if the code in the destructor calls a non-inlined function the compiler cannot elide the call due to potential side effects. Eg. We can log in destructors to printf and the compiler cannot optimize away the call.

Comment: @hauron the interface to secrethandler is conflicted. It wants me to pass a secret with an insecure container. The library should provide a secure container for secrets. Imo

Comment: @DavidThomas you'd have to ensure the compiler cannot determine where there are side-effects or is convinced there are. That could depend on the level of the optimizations, their scope (be it translation unit or link time), compiler (they should get better at this). Finally, artificial calls could slow the application down (with `printf` being an extreme).

Comment: @DavidThomas Possible.  Don't forget that LTO comes into play as well.

Comment: @DavidThomas you are absolutely correct - but the library *could* provide conversion functions, to "take over" insecure memory, and then eventually cleanse it.

Comment: @hauron printf is an example of a call that cannot be elided. I'm not suggesting it's use.

Comment: The original post does not contain these added constraints of 3rd party library interfaces. My answer was in response to the OP.

Comment: @DavidThomas your answer doesn't really address the question. *How to cleanse the std::string? Don't use std::string.*

Comment: @hauron Challenging the assumptions of a question is a perfectly legitimate answer. "The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include 'try this instead'." See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It's the onus of the question asker to specify what restrictions they have to operate under, and in cases where doing something is a bad idea, it's important and necessary to specify why you can't get away from it.

Comment: @jmpc26 Regarding challenging the question's assumptions - agreed. Nowhere in the question, however, was there made any claim `std::string` was secure or if it was a good choice. The contrary, if anything. The answer above would work much better as a comment, along with the discussion it sparked.

Comment: @hauron is `SecretHandler(std::string&& unprotected);` - a hypothetical library call or a proposed wrapper class that you can modify?

Comment: @DavidThomas proposed wrapper class that you can modify. Essentially it's up to you to ensure `std::string` will get cleared.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `std::fill` to fill the string with trash:

```
std::fill(str.begin(),str.end(), 0);
```

Do note that simply clearing or shrinking the string (with methods such `clear` or `shrink_to_fit`) does not guarantee that the string data will be deleted from the process memory. Malicious processes may dump the process memory and can extract the secret if the string is not overwritten correctly.

Bonus: Interestingly, the ability to trash the string data for security reasons forces some programming languages like Java to return passwords as `char[]` and not `String`. In Java, `String` is immutable, so "trashing" it will make a new copy of the string. Hence, you need a modifiable object like `char[]` which does not use copy-on-write.

Edit: if your compiler **does** optimize this call out, you can use specific compiler flags to make sure a trashing function will not be optimized out:

```
#ifdef WIN32

#pragma optimize("",off)
void trashString(std::string& str){
   std::fill(str.begin(),str.end(),0);
}
#pragma optimize("",on)

#endif

#ifdef __GCC__

void __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) trashString(std::string& str) {
       std::fill(str.begin(),str.end(),0);
}


#endif

#ifdef __clang__

void __attribute__ ((optnone))  trashString(std::string& str) {
       std::fill(str.begin(),str.end(),0);
}

#endif
```

Comment: I heard that "casual" ways like `std::fill` or `memset` can be optimized by compilers. If compiler sees no following usage of the string, it doesn't produce excess data change. Functions like `OpenSSL_cleanse` are made to prevent it. Am I right?

Comment: @ilotXXI that is true. OpenSSL_cleanse seems to never be optimized away.

Comment: @ilotXXI Or one can use `volatile`. Assigning the first character of a string to a volatile variable after `fill()` should prevent compiler from optimizing `fill()` away.

Comment: You may need to give some consideration to guarantees that the standard *doesn't* provide: Depending how you assembled the string, it's possible that some portion of it is left elsewhere in memory if std::string has to do a relocation, or if copies were made somewhere in the call stack.

Comment: MSVC created `memset_s` for the exact reason that `memset` can be optimized away by todays optimizing compilers.  It is getting harder and harder to trash the memory of a no longer used object as the compiler/linker sees it as unneeded.

Comment: Why are you having a hard time believing that the compiler would optimize away code that wouldn't have observable side-effects in a way that the C++ object model understands?

Comment: @Barry you are correct. a compiler can optimize the call out.

Comment: @DavidHaim thank you for the extensive answer and code snippets (I'll keep the optimizations for reference). Unfortunately, I do not know why zeroing memory isn't enough. I'd guess someone monitoring memory could be tipped that particular memory location stored a secret, rather than something just as random to the application. Since accessing the string via `front()` or combination of `operator&` and `operator[]` is compatible with cleanse, I will accept the other answers.

Comment: You create your own version of `OpenSSL_cleanse` when you already have one?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz because not everyone uses openSSL. I might be using WinHTTP instead and I want to trash the password.

Answer (score 4):

There's a better answer: **don't**!

`std::string` is a class which is designed to be userfriendly and efficient.  It was not designed with cryptography in mind, so there are few guarantees written into it to help you out.  For example, there's no guarantees that your data hasn't been copied elsewhere.  At best, you could hope that a particular compiler's implementation offers you the behavior you want.

If you actually want to treat a secret as a secret, you should handle it using tools which are designed for handling secrets.  In fact, you should develop a threat model for what capabilities your attacker has, and choose your tools accordingly.

Comment: How do you deal with the case where you have to interface with a third party that doesn't understand your `SecretKeeper` class?

Comment: @LThode And that third party doesn't have an `OtherSecretKeeper` you can convert to? Why are you using them?

Comment: @JAB -- some third parties aren't so well designed, sadly :/ (and sometimes you don't have a choice in the matter, either)

Comment: @JAB, `printf` doesn't use `SecretKeeper`. Etc.

Comment: @PaulDraper Why are you printing your secrets? Debugging purposes only, I hope.

Comment: At some point along the discussion of third party libraries and such, a threat model has to come up.  When you're talking about randomizing memory, rather than simply zeroing it out, you're after a particularly demanding level of santization.  Your third party library may simply not be the best choice given your needs.

Comment: @JAB, I'm passing them to another program, via stdout.

Or I'm base64 encoding them. Or hashing them. Or something generic that works on `std::string` data.

Comment: @PaulDraper Whatever you're doing, presumably it's an API designed for handling secret data that has methods to address your threads. If not, it's inappropriate for you to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Tested solution on CentOS 6, Debian 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 (g++/clang++, O0, O1, O2, O3):

```
secretString.resize(secretString.capacity(), '\0');
OPENSSL_cleanse(&secretString[0], secretString.size());
secretString.clear();
```

If you were really paranoid you could randomise the data in the cleansed string, so as not to give away the length of the string or a location that contained sensitive data:

```
#include <string>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef void* (*memset_t)(void*, int, size_t);

static volatile memset_t memset_func = memset;

void cleanse(std::string& to_cleanse) {
  to_cleanse.resize(to_cleanse.capacity(), '\0');
  for (int i = 0; i < to_cleanse.size(); ++i) {
    memset_func(&to_cleanse[i], rand(), 1);
  }
  to_cleanse.clear();
}
```

You could seed the rand() if you wanted also.

You could also do similar string cleansing without openssl dependency, by using explicit_bzero to null the contents:

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  std::string secretString = "ajaja";
  secretString.resize(secretString.capacity(), '\0');
  explicit_bzero(&secretString[0], secretString.size());
  secretString.clear();

  return 0;
}
```